# Javascript offsetLeft doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html

Here's code where I want to use it:

```
   if(e.keyCode==32)
   {
    var c=document.createElement("img");
    c.src="http://findicons.com/files/icons/1075/scrap/300/aqua_ball_red.png";
    c.id="ball";
    c.style.top=down+"px";
    document.body.appendChild(c);
     setTimeout(function move(){
     c.style.left=1200+"px";
   },200);
     setTimeout(function kill(){
     c.style.opacity=0;
    },700);
   }
  };
```

It's actually a moving ball which moves to certain coords after pressing space.I need to map it's coordinates when it's moving.When I use this:

```
var elem=document.getElementById("ball");
alert(elem.offsetLeft);
```

It does nothing and additionally it makes whole code in `if()` block not working.My browser is Chrome.

Here's a whole code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
 <style>
  #rocket
  {
   width:50px;
   height:50px;
   position:absolute;
   top:0;left:0;
   transition:top 0.4s, bottom 0.4s;
   }
   #ball
   {
   width:15px;
   height:15px;
   position:absolute;
   transition:left 0.5s;
   }
 </style>

 <script>
  var down=0;
  var up=0;
  document.onkeydown=function(e){
  e=e||window.event;
   if(e.keyCode==40)
   {
    down=down+30;
    document.getElementById("rocket").style.top=down+"px";
   }
   if(e.keyCode==38)
   {
    down=down-30;
    document.getElementById("rocket").style.top=down+"px";
   }
   if(e.keyCode==32)
   {
    var c=document.createElement("img");
    c.src="http://findicons.com/files/icons/1075/scrap/300/aqua_ball_red.png";
    c.id="ball";
    c.style.top=down+"px";
    document.body.appendChild(c);
     setTimeout(function move(){
     c.style.left=1200+"px";
   },200);
     setTimeout(function kill(){
     c.style.opacity=0;
    },700);
   }
  };

  document.onclick=function(e){
  var y=e.pageY;
  document.getElementById("rocket").style.top=y+"px";
  down=y;
  };

 </script>

 <img src="http://0.static.wix.com/media/a8b510_fc007f8eedd9f304c54ac6d374e3ee0b.gif_1024" id="rocket">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Regarding your two timers, a better approach would be to initiate the second timer from within the first one. If they run independently (as in your code), the delay between them is not reliable.

Comment: you create this `c` img every time the spacebar is hit, meaning you'll get duplicate element IDs.

Comment: can we see your mark up and CSS??

Answer (score 1):

The `left` property only affects elements that have `position` set to `relative`, `absolute` or `fixed`.

Answer (score 0):

For css `left` Property you have to mention that `position`

**CSS :**

```
#ball
{
  position:absolute; 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Assign your element with style `position: relative` or `position: absolute` before you want to get it's `left` or `top` property.

Try this with jQuery in the easy way:

```
alert($('#ball').offset().left);
```

or

```
var elem=document.getElementById("ball");
alert(elem.style.left);
```